# In a Transactional function, calling clear() detach all entities?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactional, persist

I am using Hibernate as JPA provider and in a function, I am creating an instance of different entities. Once I call `clear()` for one entity, I can't `persist()` the other entities. My code is pretty more complicated, and at a point I am obliged to call `flush()` and `clear()` for one type of entities (and NOT for the other types) in order to free some memory.

A simplification of my code is as follow:

```
@Transactional
void function()
{
    EntityType1 entity1 = new  EntityType1();
    EntityType2 entity2 = new  EntityType2();

    //...... do operations on entity1
    entity1.persist();
    entity1.flush();
    entity1.clear();

    //...... do operations on entity2
    entity2.persist();
}
```

When calling `entity2.persist()` I have the following error:
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist

Comment: Does your `entity2` already have an `id` assigned? ... if so, Hibernate is expecting to Update the entity rather than persist a new instance. In this case call `merge()` to attach the instance before calling `persist()`

Comment: Hi Brad, yes! My entity2 has an id assigned! thank you a lot for the advice! but what is the relation with between clearing entity1 and persisting entity2 using merge() rather than persist()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely your `entity2` already has an `@Id` assigned and therefore Hibernate is expecting to *Update* the existing entity rather than persist a new instance. This is why Hibernate considers `entity2` to be *detached*.

Calling `entity2.merge()` will provide you with an associated entity to the Hibernate session. Be warned that [merge()](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#merge%28java.lang.Object%29) returns a new instance of your entity that is the persisted copy.

Example

```
EntityType2 entityPersisted = entity2.merge();

entityPersisted.getSomething();  // your persisted instance
entity2.getSomething();  // still your detached instance
```

Calling [clear()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#clear%28%29) evicts your entire session cache so all entites you have with an `@Id` will be considered *detached*.

If you only want to remove the one entity from the session cache use [evict()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict%28java.lang.Object%29)